# How to make a responsive sticky/fixed position (links floated right) with dropdown links?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a responsive drop-down menu which has the following criteria; the links are floated right; the menu is responsive; and there is a drop-down menu.

I have tried modifying the w3 schools responsive navbar but there always seems to be an issue which I cannot resolve. A JSfiddle of the w3 schools responsive navbar https://jsfiddle.net/g19h45ep/3/

```
testing code
```

Comment: you can use bootstrap also for that and use `text-align: right` to float your link right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you all links are in right side and do you want to move home button to left or hamburger to left ?

- ALREADY ALIGN TO RIGHT

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}


.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child),
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a {
    float: right;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: left;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>

    <div style="padding-left:16px">
      <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
      <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
      <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
    </div>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
          x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
          x.className = "topnav";
        }
      }

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

- TEXT ALIGN RIGHT WHEN CLICK**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}


.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child),
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>

    <div style="padding-left:16px">
      <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
      <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
      <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
    </div>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
          x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
          x.className = "topnav";
        }
      }

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

---

*Edit*

- HOME LINE IN SEPARATE LINE WITH FIXED NAVBAR

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

div.topnav > a:first-child {
   display: none;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}


.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
div.topnav > a:first-child {
   display: block;
}
  .topnav a:not(:first-child),
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="#home"></a>
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>

    <div style="padding-left:16px">
      <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
      <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
      <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
      <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
      <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
      <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
      <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
      <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
      <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
      <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
      <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
      <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
      <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
      <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
      <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
      <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
      <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
      <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
      <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
      <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
      <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
    </div>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
          x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
          x.className = "topnav";
        }
      }

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, in the responsive breakpoint, you are trying to have "News", "Contact", "Dropdown", and "About" align right?  If so, I hope this helps: 
https://jsfiddle.net/fLjged3s/

I added the following in the css:

```
.topnav a:nth-child(n+2) {
  text-align: right !important;
}
```

And text-align: right to .dropdown .dropbtn

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.topnav a:nth-child(n+2) {
  text-align: right !important;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: right !important;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child),
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>

    <div style="padding-left:16px">
      <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
      <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
      <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
    </div>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
          x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
          x.className = "topnav";
        }
      }

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: In this JSfiddle, the hamburger is now in the right place, but I would like the other text to be left aligned and the home to be in the under the original navbar not on it, when the width is reduced. Also something messed up with the dropdown making the first one align different. Thanks again,